# Is there a good way to style HTML elements and re-expose all of their events in a Svelte component?

Tags: css, svelte, svelte-3

How would I go about styling HTML elements and re-exposing all of their events in a Svelte component? (essentially, I'm looking for the Svelte way to do [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com))

For example, I'm trying to style a regular HTML `button` and expose it a reusable component:

```html
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
</script>

<button
  on:click={() => dispatch("click")}
  on:mouseover={() => dispatch("mouseover")}
  {/* ...and so on for every other event */}
>
  <slot />
</button>

<style>
  button {
    /* ... */
  }
</style>
```

Is there any way to avoid having to make every single event on the `button` HTML element call `dispatch` to propagate the event through the parent? Is there a simpler way?

I've tried searching, and most places point me to just use CSS-in-JS, but I don't want to forego all the optimizations having my styles written purely in Svelte give me (lower bundle sizes, better performance, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward events by just listing them *without* event handler:

```html
<button {...$$restProps} on:click on:focus on:hover ...>
```

No need to dispatch, but you currently cannot automatically forward *all* events, they still need to be listed. ([Issue on that](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2837))

Properties are passed via `$$restProps`, which includes all not explicitly defined properties (not events). ([Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-attributes-and-props))

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **$$restProps object** to pass all the events and properties of
the button to the component:

**Script**

```
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  export let $$restProps;
</script>

<button on:click={() => dispatch("click")} {...$$restProps}>
<slot />
```

**Styling**

```
<style>
  button {
    /* ... */
  }
</style>
```

Then use this component like this:

```
<StyledButton class="my-button" on:click={() => console.log("clicked!")}>
  Click me!
</StyledButton>
```